# How to check if any errors exist in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using React + Redux, and redux-form for form processing and validation.  So far, it's been pretty easy to use and I can easily check the validation state of individual form fields using field.touched and field.error, but I can't seem to find any method or property which will tell me if there are any errors across the entire form.  The way React works, any form will generate a bunch of errors as soon as it's loaded, which is why you need to use field.touched to test individual fields.

What I'm looking to do is to have some universal markup displayed if there are any errors anywhere in the form, but only once touched.  So really, I was hoping there was something like form.touched and form.error.  I have a design in mind for a helper function which will check all fields in a form and return a boolean but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

**UPDATE:**
As per Andy_D's answer, I've updated my code to use the form-level properties `dirty` and `invalid` but `dirty` doesn't seem to update properly.  After submitting the form and seeing individual field-level errors, the form is still showing `dirty: false`.

Included below is a simplified version of my code as well as the contents of the this.props object after submitting the form.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { makeBooking } from '../actions/index';

class PaymentBooking extends Component {
    render() {
        const { fields: { school }, handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.makeBooking)}>
                {
                    console.log(this)
                }
                {
                    this.props.dirty && this.props.invalid ? <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Test error wrapper</div> : ''
                }
                <h2>Make a New Payment Booking</h2>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading">Payment Information</div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className={`form-group ${school.touched && school.invalid ? 'has-error' : ''}`}>
                            <label htmlFor="school" className="col-lg-2 control-label">Your School</label>
                            <div className="col-lg-10">
                                <select name="school" className="form-control" {...school}>
                                    <option value="MIT">MIT</option>
                                    <option value="Stanford">Stanford</option>
                                    <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-submit">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Book a Payment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

function validate(values) {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.school)
        errors.school = 'School is a required field';

    return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'PaymentBookingForm',
    fields: ['school'],
    validate
}, null, {makeBooking})(PaymentBooking);
```

this.props after submit:

```
{
  "readonly": false,
  "asyncValidating": false,
  "dirty": false,
  "errors": {
    "school": "School is a required field"
  },
  "fields": {
    "school": {
      "name": "school",
      "defaultChecked": false,
      "valid": false,
      "invalid": true,
      "dirty": false,
      "pristine": true,
      "error": "School is a required field",
      "active": false,
      "touched": true,
      "visited": false
    }
  },
  "invalid": true,
  "pristine": true,
  "submitting": false,
  "submitFailed": true,
  "valid": false,
  "values": {}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's there in the props for you - you're looking for the form-level props `pristine` and `valid`.

After submit, `pristine` will reset, but if the request is unsuccessful, you'll get a `submitFailed` prop.

`(!pristine || submitFailed) && !valid && <ErrorMessage />`

There are also props for the inverses, so you could use

`(dirty || submitFailed) && invalid`

As I mentioned in my comment, I would prevent submit if the form is invalid.

```
<button
  type="submit"
  className="btn btn-primary"
  disabled={pristine || invalid}
>Book a Payment</button>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it might be as simple as that.  Unfortunately, it's not working for me.  When I submit my form, my field level properties update and the individual errors show, but the field level properties don't seem to update.  At least, pristine stays true and dirty stays false.  I'll try to update my question with code to see if anyone can identify a more specific issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: The issue is that it's pristine despite errors _after_ submit?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The field errors show, which means that the individual field.touched properties are being updated, but the pristine is still true after error/submit and dirty is still false as well.

Comment: I'm probably missing something about your use case, but why not prevent submit (disable the button/submit input) if the form is invalid? Nevertheless, I think you can use `submitFailed` - editing the answer.

Comment: I thought that it was the job of the `handleSubmit()` function to prevent the form's submission if it's invalid?  Anyway, I updated the code to use `submitFailed` and that works, but I'll keep your advice about disabling the submit button in mind for future patterns.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, I found myself in this position just now. I needed to know if there were any active field errors in a Redux-Form so that I could disable the Submit button in the form.

My use case might not be quite the same as OPs, but Andy_D's response got me going in the right direction; however, I didn't find `pristine`, `dirty`, or `pure` useful in my case. Once those are toggled from their default value, they stay that way until the component is reloaded.

`valid` and `invalid` do toggle back and forth based on whether the form had errors or did not. So in my case, I can do the following:

```
<button 
    disabled={ this.props.invalid }
    type='submit' 
    className='btn btn-primary'
>
    Submit
</button>
```

I tried using something like Redux-Form's `formValueSelector()` and had no luck there, so this was the best solution I could find that works for me.